# Choice between an adjusted cosine similarity vs regular cosine similarity

Tags: recommendation-engine, cosine-similarity, collaborative-filtering

I'm working on an item-based CF which uses an adjusted cosine similarity. I have recently added a regular cosine similarity and I got totally different results. Now my question is which fits better considering my data?

This is a possible scenario of users, items and ratings

```
         User 1 | User 2 | User 3 | User 4 | User 5
Item 1 |   5    |    1   |   1    |   5    |   5
Item 2 |   5    |    1   |   2    |   4    |   5
Item 3 |   1    |    5   |   4    |   2    |   3
```

Considering this data, you'd conclude that item 1 and item 2 are relatively 'similar'. Here are the results of the different similarity coefficients:

Similarity between Item 1 and Item 2
`Adjusted cosine similarity = 0.865`
`Regular cosine similarity = 0.987`
*I rounded them off for this example*

You can see this is basically the same, but when you try to calculate a similarity between Item 2 and 3 (Which aren't similar at all) it results in totally different results:

Similarity between Item 2 and Item 3
`Adjusted cosine similarity = -0.955`
`Regular cosine similarity = 0.656`
*I rounded them off for this example*

Which of these would be 'better'? I assume using an adjusted cosine similarity works better since it take the average rating of the user into account, but why would a regular cosine similarity result in a positive number for such 'different' items? Should I just refrain from using the regular cosine similarity in general or only for certain scenarios?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why would a regular cosine similarity result in a positive number for such 'different' items?

As you already mentioned in the example, `Adjusted Cosine Similarity` reflects the differences better than the `Regular Cosine Similarity` in certain circumstances.

`Regular Cosine Similarity` by the definition reflects differences in direction, but not the location.

[image]

`dist(A,B)`  is the `Euclidean Distance` between A and B. It's clear that the cosine similarity will remain the same if any vector extends in its own direction.

Let's assume the user give scores in 0~5 to two movies.

```
from scipy import spatial
import numpy as np
a = np.array([2.0,1.0])  
b = np.array([5.0,3.0])
1 - spatial.distance.cosine(a,b)
#----------------------
# 0.99705448550158149
#----------------------
c = np.array([5.0,4.0])
1 - spatial.distance.cosine(c,b)
#----------------------
# 0.99099243041032326
#----------------------
```

[image]

Intuitively we would say user `b` and `c` have similar tastes, and `a` is quite different from them. But the regular cosine similarity tells us a wrong story.

Let's calculate the `Adjusted Cosine Similarity`, first minus the mean of `x` and `y`

```
mean_ab = sum(sum(a,b)) / 4  
# mean_ab : 3.5
# adjusted vectors : [-1.5, -2.5] , [1.5, -0.5]
1 - spatial.distance.cosine(a - mean_ab, b - mean_ab)
#----------------------
# -0.21693045781865616
#----------------------
mean_cb = sum(sum(c,b)) / 4
# mean_cb : 6.5
# adjusted vectors : [-1.5, -3.5] , [-1.5, -2.5]
1 - spatial.distance.cosine(c - mean_cb, b - mean_cb)
#----------------------
# 0.99083016804429891
#----------------------
```

It's clear to see the adjustment is meaningful.

> Should I just refrain from using the regular cosine similarity in general or only for certain scenarios?

When you find there's a problem, use the suitable one.

I still think the regular cosine similarity is useful in scenarios where we want less sensitivity on the scale of vectors. For example, if the scores [2,1] is considered as very similar to [4,2] or [8,4], the regular will do a fine job.